# Keeping the links to the files when moving a sharepoint folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to reorganize the microsoft sharepoint of my team, into thematic folders, but I'd like to keep the links to the original files after moving them. Do you know if it's possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean file sharing link? If true, please check this [article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-move-documents-between-sharepoint-sites-without-breaking-the-sharing-links/):

When you move the files within site (inside of a library or between libraries on the same site), all the previously shared links to those files will still keep working!

When you move the files to a totally different site,remember to check the `Keep sharing with the same people` box:

[image]

In this way, the previously shared link will still work for the recipient.

**Limitations**

- The ability to keep sharing links is only available for files, not
  folders
- When a shared folder is moved to another site, the link will stop
  working. The recipient will receive This link has been removed
  message.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for files either. This only works if they're directly shared with. But if they have links shared with them, it drops who the link. The links have the site name in them so they can't possibly persist.

Comment: Apparently, it depends on the sharing method: When using "People you choose", "Anzone", or "People in <organisation xy>", this works fine. However, when using "People with existing access", the link contains path and file name and breaks when moving.